# Script attached to gameObject not functioning but enabled (with checkmark in inspector) after disabling and then re-enabling again (UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a JoyStick script attached to a player prefab and I disabled it while my timer is not equal to 0 and re-enable it. It's being re-enabled but my player cannot move anymore even though the script is checked on the inspector.

[image]

[image]

[image]

so the first picture shows that the joystick is checked and enabled before i click the start game button which will initiate a timer

the second picture shows that while the timer goes, the script is disabled

and the third shows that it's being enabled again but i can't seem to make my prefab move. FYI, it's moving before i disable the script.

Comment: You dont move prefabs. You move instantiated objects.

Answer (score -1):

It's because when you disable it you are causing some issues with some variables or gameObjects that probably were accessing to that script.
For example :

```
public int counter
```

If in another script you are accessing to that counter

```
Player.counter = n + 1;
```

It is giving to you an error when you disable the script and even if you re-able it, it won't work again because of the errors. The same can occur for prefab called, public functions and so on.
Instead of disabling that script you should add a bool called `isTimerZero` and put it in the movement section for example

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown("a") && isTimerZero == false)
 // move the player
 else
 // don't move it
```

In this way you will just change the bool to true when timer is 0, and it won't cause problems

Comment: will try this right now and will get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: by the way, I'm not necessarily "moving" the prefab. It should depend on the player if he wants to move the joystick or not so I think I will be required to disable the joystick script?

Comment: you will never need to disable a script, even the joystick uses a system of Inputs inside the player script, you only need to check them and it will look like it is disabled

Comment: Accessing or setting a field/property value has nothing to do with Unity's enabled or disabled state .. the only thing this does is not invoking the `Update` calls anymore ... you can still call whatever method or access fields as usual on disabled components ...

Comment: yeah but a movement system will be in Update() and to it will create errors @derHugo